# exe created by pyinstaller not working

Tags: python, ios, windows-7, exe, pyinstaller

I have a mac with parallels that have win7 on it.
When I create an exe using pyinstaller from the IOS - it runs smoothly there.
When I create it from win7 and try to run it there, it immediately shuts down, and does not show any error - it simply appears and disappears.
I tried dragging it to the command prompt but I don't see any error there as well..
I believe it opens and does not run at all beacause when I add print ("hi) at the top of the python script I don't see it at the command prompt.

I am running python 2.7, my windows is Win7 64 bit and the IOS is El Capitan 10.11.2
and the command I used is: pyinstaller --onefile --windowed myCode.py
please advice,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows console should wait for an input. I bet your code works and terminate itself immediately because you didn't put raw_input at the last line of your code.

put

```
raw_input()
```

to your last line.

Comment: Thanks Metin, added this line, which brought me one step closer to the solution but I got "myCode returned -1"